# CollectionView content does not expand to fill screen on screen roration for visible area

Tags: forms, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Forms app with a CollectionView.  The contents of the view (inside the DataTemplate) are not expanding when the screen rotates - until I scroll down and scroll back up.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout x:Name="outerStack" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <CollectionView Margin="0,0,0,10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding testObject}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemplate">
                    <Frame BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#343434" Margin="0,1,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <!--content would go here-->
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Initially, the gray bars expand all the way to the end in portrait mode. On screen rotation, the gray bars do not expand all the way to the end. Until...  I start scrolling up and down. Once I do that, the gray bards draw correctly once off screen.

[image: Initially, the gray bars expand all the way to the end in portrait mode]

[image: On screen rotation, the gray bars do not expand all the way to the end. Until...]

[image: I start scrolling up and down. Once I do that, the gray bards draw correctly once off screen.]

Any idea how I make it so that the contents of the CollectionView refresh correctly right away on screen rotation?

Comment: Hi, which version of visual studio you used , I expected the same phenemenon.

Comment: It is visual studio 2017.  Latest version of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Okey , got it ,mine is in VS2019. It 's a strange phenemon.I will check it.

Comment: Add VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" to your stacklayout + collectionview and let us know

Comment: There was no change.  Still the same results.

Comment: Any idea on this?

Comment: Was it fixed in latest versions? cannot reproduce